# How to search for equations which contain space in their label name?

Tags: texstudio

I'm labeling my equations using:

```
\label{eq: equation1}
```

Now, when I put a reference to that equation, typing

```
\eqref{eq:}
```

a small popup appears with all my labelled equations. I find this a very convenient way to choose from my labelled equations. However, when I add the space between "eq:" and "equation", that popup disappears. This makes it really hard to use that popup, if, for example, I only remember the first few letters from my equation name. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: don't put spaces in the label? (spaces do more or less work but are not recommended)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.